# AlertManager queue is dropping messages

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I have been using alertmanager to send alerts to pagerduty, and after a while I started getting the following error:
`level=warn ts=2021-04-02T10:43:01.239Z caller=delegate.go:272 component=cluster msg="dropping messages because too many are queued" current=4102 limit=4096`
This happens every 15 minutes.

Is there a way to:

1. increase the queue size?
2. connect to the queue and check what makes it stuck?
3. see some kind of monitoring for the queue?

I tried to search for anything that will allow me to connect to it, but have not found anything.

Comment: Are you getting ```dropping messages because too many are queued" current=4102 limit=4096``` for webhook receiver ?